# Composite primary key with Entity Framework 6 fluent API without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

i found many post about this but simply don't find a solution i like.

I have a class like this

```
public Class1{
    int Year{get;set;}
    Class2 Class2Field {get;set;}
    //.... other non key field
}
```

and i want to map the key in this way:

```
HasKey(u => new { u.Class1.Year, u.Class1.Class2Field.id });
```

i don't wan't a Class2Field.Id property in my object: don't need and don't like.

it's the ORM that have to map it correctly, without forcing domain model to have unuseful property.

Is there a work-aroud to do this?

Only idea i have is to create a guid that will be my object key and make actual key only required property, something like this:

```
public Class1{
    int Id{get;set;}
    int Year{get;set;}
    Class2 Class2Field {get;set;}
    //.... other non key field
}

HasKey(u => new { u.Class1.Id});
```

but still don't like this very much

Can NHibernate fluent solve this problem?

Comment: No one have better idea?

Comment: just hoping to get some answers